# R shiny: text won't wrap within splitLayout()

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am working within a `tabPanel` for a webtool I am creating and need two columns. My predecessor used `fluidPage()` from within the `tabPanel`, but that causes the text and figures I want to add to spill outside of the panel.

The easiest solution I have found is to use splitLayout(), which works great for my figures, however, any lines of text I add within a splitLayout will not wrap, and instead creates a slider bar:

```
splitLayout(
                       h5(strong("Projected HCV Prevalence with DAAs")),
                       h5(strong("Projected HCV Prevalence without Treatment")),
                       cellArgs = list(style='padding:0px; word-wrap: break-word;', align="center")
                     ),
```

Even removing the html code doesn't fix it. Any solutions?

Comment: Are you looking for a dynamic solution or is something static ok with you? Have you tried line breaks? e.g., `"Projected HCV Prevalence\nwithout Treatment"`